# How to shorten the group name in bibtex so that only the abbreviation appears in the text

Tags: author, bibtex

I would like to cite a report by the European Commission in bibtex (latex). In the references list I would like to have the full name but in the main text I would only like the abbreviation to appear. I am using the elsarticle-harv bibliographystyle.

Here is an example:

Main text:
The European Commission agreed in 2016 that ..... (EC, 2016).

References:
European Commission (EC), 2016. Communication from the ......

Here is my current bibentry:

```
@misc{EC2016,
    title = {{Communication from the Commission to the European Parliament, the Council, the European Economic and Social Committee and the Committee of the Regions: An EU Strategy on Heating and Cooling}},
    author = {{EC}},
    year = {2016}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a cite alias through the natbib package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\defcitealias{EC2016}{(EC, 2016)}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{EC2016, title = {{Communication from the Commission to the European Parliament, the Council, the European Economic and Social Committee and the Committee of the Regions: An EU Strategy on Heating and Cooling}}, author = {{European Commission (EC)}}, year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}
\citetalias{EC2016}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```